# select different column python pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a question how to select different column(create new series) based on another column value. raw data as following：

```
              DEST_ZIP5   EXP_EDD_FRC_DAY  GND_EDD_FRC_DAY  \
        0     00501                      5                6   
        1     00544                      5                6   
        2     01001                      4                8   
        3     01001                      4                8   
        4     01001                      4                8  

      EXP_DAY_2  EXP_DAY_3  EXP_DAY_4  EXP_DAY_5           ...            \
    0        0.0       1.00       1.00        1.0           ...             
    1        0.0       1.00       1.00        1.0           ...             
    2        0.0       0.85       1.00        1.0           ...             
    3        0.0       1.00       1.00        1.0           ...             
    4        0.0       0.85       0.85        1.0           ...             


       GND_DAY_3  GND_DAY_4  GND_DAY_5  GND_DAY_6  GND_DAY_7  GND_DAY_8  \
    0        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
    1        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
    2        0.0        0.0       0.16       0.33       0.83       1.00   
    3        0.0        0.0       0.00       0.14       0.71       0.85   
    4        0.1        0.1       0.20       0.40       0.40       0.60
```

I want to have two new data serize which get the number value of for responding column.
     (the row 1, EXP_EDD_FRC_DAY   =5, so, return df[EXP_DAY_5]. 
     GND_EDD_FRC_DAY  =6, return df[GND_DAY_6]

```
            DEST_ZIP5   EXP_percentage  GND_percentage  \
        0     00501                      1.0                NaN   
        1     00544                      1.0                NaN   
        2     01001                      1.0                 1.00   
        3     01001                      1.0                0.85   
        4     01001                      0.85                0.60
```

I found function lookup. Not not sure how to use that.

Thank you very much

-

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
c = df['EXP_EDD_FRC_DAY'].astype(str).radd('GND_DAY_')
new_series = pd.Series(df.lookup(df.index, c), df.index)
```